# How to read a .txt file to graph a plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a .txt file that I update every 15 seconds with new data entries in the following format:

```
13:57:06,389,492,140
13:57:21,139,181,484
13:57:36,483,294,414
13:57:51,373,382,195
13:58:06,425,360,277
13:58:21,394,310,307
13:58:36,327,291,303
13:58:52,461,352,133
13:59:07,242,426,492
13:59:22,389,448,296
13:59:37,301,443,366
13:59:52,212,229,106
14:02:08,112,442,347
14:02:23,284,361,329
14:02:39,353,438,467
14:02:54,254,385,401
14:03:09,217,125,410
14:03:24,295,266,326
14:03:39,389,209,196
14:03:54,323,203,147
14:04:10,346,230,365
14:04:25,143,181,261
14:04:40,294,104,230
14:04:55,376,264,357
```

Each line consists of a timestamp followed by three numerical values, which are readings from a PLC (Programmable Logic Controller). I aim to plot these values on a graph, displaying three plots simultaneously to represent each set of readings over time.

However, when attempting to read this .txt file with pandas, I encountered difficulties. It seems my approach might not be suitable for handling .txt files, as I'm more familiar with pandas handling CSV files. Could someone guide me on how to correctly read this data into a DataFrame, separate the values, and create a plot with three series represented?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.txt", header=None) # header=None <-- assuming you have no header row
df.columns = ["time", "col1", "col2", "col3"]  # give names to columns

plt.plot(df["time"], df["col1"], label="Col 1")
plt.plot(df["time"], df["col2"], label="Col 2")
plt.plot(df["time"], df["col3"], label="Col 3")

plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.title("My Graph")


plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This creates this graph:

[image]

---

OR bar graph:

```py
# ...

bar_width = 0.25
index = np.arange(len(df))

plt.bar(index, df["col1"], bar_width, label="Col 1")
plt.bar(index + bar_width, df["col2"], bar_width, label="Col 2")
plt.bar(index + 2 * bar_width, df["col3"], bar_width, label="Col 3")

plt.xticks(index + bar_width, df["time"], rotation=45)
# ...
```

Creates this graph:

[image]